# Major slowness in 1% of nginx responses under load

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx

Ubuntu 14.04

```
apt-get install nginx apache2-utils
```

Then `vi /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` to these contents:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;

  location / {
    return 200 "Ok";
  }
}
```

`service nginx restart`

Running:

```
ab -c 500 -k -n 100000 127.0.0.1/
```

I get the result:

```
Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%      0
  66%      0
  75%      0
  80%      0
  90%      0
  95%      0
  98%     14
  99%    489
 100%   3065 (longest request)
```

Ok, so I get most of the responses very fast (which is to be expected), but about 1% (nearly 1000 requests) of responses are very slow. (0.5s - 3s)

Why is this happening? How to find the source of problem? I guessing kernel/sysctl, but how to find out exactly what's up?

---

*UPDATE1*

I tried to replace `ab` with `siege` and result is the same.

```
siege -c 500 -r 200 -b 127.0.0.1/

....
Concurrency:              240.67
Successful transactions:      100000
Failed transactions:               0
Longest transaction:            1.50
Shortest transaction:           0.00
```

I tried changing some variables in `nginx` and restarting server after each change and re-running `ab`.

```
worker_processes 10;

worker_connections 7680;

multi_accept on;

events { use select; }

events { use poll; }

events { use epoll; }
```

I tried adjusting `sysctl` and re-running test each time:

```
net.core.somaxconn=5120 # including listen directive backlog in nginx

net.core.netdev_max_backlog=5120
```

I raised number of open files to 5000000 and re-run test.

I tried some other tcp congestion control methods and re-run the test each time.

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control=hybla

sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control=illinois

sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control=lp

sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control=probe

sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control=scalable

sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control=vegas

sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control=veno

sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control=westwood

sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control=yeah
```

I tried more sysctl vars and re-run the test each time.

```
sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=67108864 

sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_rmem='4096 87380 33554432'

sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_wmem='4096 65536 33554432'

sysctl -w net.core.netdev_max_backlog=30000

sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control=htcp

sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_mtu_probing=1

sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=134217728 

sysctl -w net.core.wmem_max=134217728 

sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_rmem='4096 87380 67108864'

sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_wmem='4096 65536 67108864'

sysctl -w net.core.netdev_max_backlog=250000

sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control=htcp

sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_mtu_probing=1
```

Finally, I downloaded `golang` and compiled the server and tested `ab` against this basic server - everything is the same.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "OK")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

go run test.go
```

Nothing seems to affect this 1%.

*UPDATE2*

Ok, this might have something to do with CPU saturation. On 16-core GCE machine the effect is much better and less noticeable. The original test was done on 1-core Digital Ocean instance.

*UPDATE3*

Yep, has to be something with CPU. No effect on 4-core GCE. (Added as answer)

Comment: @AndrewHenle I tried most of the sysctl recommendations that I have googled, I compiled golang's http server (and see the same result). I tried it on DigitalOcean and on Dedicated servers and in OpenVZ containers. I tried a lot of recipes that help tuning nginx params. Frankly, a lot of random movements found by googling stuff. But none of those help. That's where I decided that probably StackOverflow's brain is the last point of hope for solution.

Comment: Have you tried using different arguments to `ab`?  Changing the concurrency and/or the number of requests?  Using different TCP window sizes?  See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html

Comment: Sure, the result, of course, differs based on that. The less concurrency (-c) - the less chance of this random behavior and it is less severe. But, anyways, it seems really weird. A lot of near zero response times and very slow 1% responses. It seems like it should be "everything is slightly slower", not "just 1% of very-very slow ones". So, I hoping for some kind of pointer on how to hunt for this thing.

Comment: Have you read this at all? https://blog.cloudflare.com/the-story-of-one-latency-spike/

Comment: @parkamark Yes, thank you, that was the first thing I tried. Didn't help. The effect stayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the answer is - not enough CPU

4-core GCE

```
  Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
    50%      8
    66%     12
    75%     16
    80%     17
    90%     24
    95%     28
    98%     35
    99%     41
   100%     63 (longest request)
```

1-core GCE

```
Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%      0
  66%      0
  75%      0
  80%      0
  90%      0
  95%      0
  98%      4
  99%    509
 100%   3597 (longest request)
```